# Setting Properties in JavaScript Object Which Operator to Use

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm confused by the = vs. : when assigning a value to a property in an object

Now I know that there are a couple ways to create an object:

- Object Literal
- Object Constructor

With an object Literal you would use ":" to assign a value to a property:

var myObject = {firstName: "John", lastName="Smith" };

There we are using ":" to set the value to the property.

I also know a function itself is an object.  And you can probably expose public properties from there as part of the function being an object?

So is it if you're assigning a function to a property that you'd use "="?  I am assuming yet but what about something like this:

```
var phantom = require('phantom');

var World = function World(callback) {

    phantom.create("--web-security=no", "--ignore-ssl-errors=yes", { port: 12345 }, function (ph) {
        var phantomProcess = ph;

        createBrowserPage = function(){
            phantomProcess.createPage(function(page) {

                this.headlessPage = page;
            })
        };
    });

    callback();
};

module.exports.World = World;
```

I assume I have this right in that I want to expose createBrowserPage through exports.  I wouldn't use createBrowserPage: and use a ":" instead of "=" to assign that anonymous function to the createBrowserPage property right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=` is used for assignment in a Javascript statement as in:

```
variable = "foo";
```

`:` is used in an object literal declaration between a property `name: value` as in:

```
var obj = {
    prop1: value1,
    prop2: value2
};
```

If you want to expose your `createBrowserPage()` function through exports, you have several options, some of which involve creating an object and some of which involve assigning a property to an object.  Which you choose and how you declare it leads to whether you use `:` or `=`.  It depends upon which way you choose to write the javascript code that exposes `createBrowserPage()`.  There is no single answer there.  I will offer you a couple options.

If, in one statement, you want to assign one new property to the exports object, then you would use `=` like this:

```
module.exports.myFunc1 = myLocalFunction1;
```

If, in one statement, you wish to assign all your exported functions, then you would assign an object that was assigned with `=`, but used `:` in the declaration of the object like this:

```
module.exports = {
    myFunc1: myLocalFunction1,
    myfunc2: myLocalFunction2
};
```

In the first example, you are adding one new property to the exports object and assigning that property a value.

In the second example, you are declaring a new Javascript literal object (which uses `prop: value` syntax to declare its properties.  And, then you are assigning that whole object to `module.exports` which actually replaces the  entire existing `exports` object with a new one and this new object has two properties on it.

Comment: could you also do module.exports = { myFunc1: function(){...code here}, myFunc2: function(){...code here}}; and assign anonymous functions in object literals?  I assume the answer is yet.

Comment: So also is there a third option.  Lets say you did module.exports.myFunc1 = someOtherVariable where myFunc1 is an -existing- method on the exports object and here you're overriding that one method and overwriting that method with your someOtherVariable.  In otherwords you can update / overwrite -existing- properties or methods with = too right?

Comment: @WeDoTDD - yes, `=` will replace a previously existing value too and yes the functions could be inline anonymous functions rather than a reference to a named function.  In Javascript a function reference can be either a named function or an inline anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing, but if you're interested in the precise meaning and grammar of `:` and `=` it's like this:

**The colon (`:`) symbol** is *not* an operator, it is part of the [litteral object notation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5) syntax and separates *property names* (a litteral string or simple identifier) from their *value* (any expression). Colons are only used in that context and as part of the trinary conditional operator (`?:`).

Something in curly brackets is parsed as a litteral object if and only if the `{` is not the first character in the instruction (otherwise it defines a block) and does not follow a `function` expression or declaration.

**The assignment operator (`=`)** ([spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1)) is a binary operator, it can be used in any expression as long as its left operand is a valid left-hand-side expression, and it returns the value of the right operand. Unless strict mode is used, it will silently fail to assign a value to read-only properties.

Comment: Thanks, the other guy kinda gave me more and answered it clearer for me but thanks for your answer regardless.

Comment: also good point on the strict mode in the behavior that happens with and without strict.